# Junit Testing with .launch file

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, acceptance-testing

I have created some test classes. All are working fine with `.launch` file. I'm running these classes using right click, launch file and choose RunAs option.

And my questions are,

1. Why do we need a `.launch` file?
2. How can I run test classes without `.launch` files?

This is a sample from the launch file:

```
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspath‌​Entry id=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.classpathentry.defaultCla‌​sspath&quot;&gt;&#13‌​;&#10;&lt;memento exportedEntriesOnly=&quot;false&quot; project=&quot;ProcessEvent&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;/runtimeC‌​lasspathEntry&gt;&#1‌​3;&#10;"/>
```

Comment: Can you share mode details with us? I believe the `.launch` file belongs to your IDE. So, which IDE do you use? What's the layout of your test / prod classes? What is in your `.launch` file?

Comment: Im using eclips Mars version. launch files in the classpath

Comment: sample-

<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry id=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.classpathentry.defaultClasspath&quot;&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;memento exportedEntriesOnly=&quot;false&quot; project=&quot;ProcessEvent&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;/runtimeClasspathEntry&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>

Answer (score 0):

The `.launch` file is easy: you need it because the eclipse test harness requires that.

There are lots of JUnit [test runners](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/test-runners) and test harnesses available

- You can group them into [suites](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Aggregating-tests-in-suites).
- You can scan the test files within a directory
- You can use the [Jenkins plugi](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin)n too to run your class files within a CI server.

So, what exactly do you want to do?